# Google Charts DataTable unknown

Tags: google-visualization, television, google-datatable

I'm using Google Charts to print out some cool charts. It works great in all my browsers.
But the application that I'm building is a HbbTv app. In that enviroment Google Charts gives me an error when he tries to create a DataTable.

The google.visualization object exist, but arrayToTable doesn't exist...
When I try to use DataTable() (creating a new empty DataTable) I get an error dat new google.visualization.DataTable() isn't a constructor...

Somebody known how this could happen?

Some additional info:

- The google.visualisation is loaded (but it only count 3 elements instead of 51)
- The HbbTv enviroment is a Opera 9.8

Thanks!

Code:

```
//My code for creating a data table from an array
var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data, false);

// My code for creating a DataTable with a new instance
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Hour');
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Amount');
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Average');
dataTable.addRows(data);
```

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: Added some code, this code works in a browsers like FireFox, Chrome and even the Opera TV Emulator

Comment: I found out that it craches on setting the NumberFormat funtion. It loads Version, JSHash en LoadArgs, but nothing else. The next one should be NumberFormat.

Comment: What packages are you loading? I suspect that your function is being called before the visualization packages have completed loading.

Comment: I'm loading the corechart package. Everything should be loaded. Because I use the callback function to start my application.

Comment: Got some more info:
- The issue occurs with the Opera SDK 3.3 and lower
- This is the error that I get: Syntax error at line 241 while loading: expected ')', got keyword 'in'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed in the Google Visualization 1.1 (release canidate).
So very soon it will be fixed in the production version.